# Connecting local mongodb from docker container ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, docker

I am trying to connect local mongodb from a docker container ruby on rails application.
I have added the variable as `env MONGODB_URI` in envFile file with value:

`MONGODB_URI=mongodb://username:password@host:27017/database`

command I am using to run the image in container:

`docker run -p 80:80 --env-file ~/envFile -v ~/.ssh/filename:/tmp/filename --name=name imagename`

But it's not connecting with mongodb. I am new in working with docker.

Comment: can you ping you "host" from inside the container + your "host" is NOT localhost?

Comment: Can you please explain how to ping my host. And yes, my host is localhost

Answer (score 0):

When you point to your `localhost` from inside your container then you'll point to the `localhost` of your container and not the `localhost` from your host system.

One way to workaround your issue is using the `host` network instead the default `bridge`: Deploy your app container in the `host` network:

```
 docker run .. --net=host ..
```

Another way to solve this is using the `--add-host` option.

```
docker run .. --add-host="localhost:192.168.0.133" ...
```

In this case `192.168.0.133` is my `en0` IP address of my computer (check `ifconfig`).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but it does not help. Let me explain you a bit more what I am doing. I might do something wrong.

• I am adding the mongoid.yml in dockerignore file

• Adding env MONGODB_URI in env.config file (which is added in dockerFile)

• Put value of env MONGODB_URI in envFile where the hostname is the hostname from mongoid.yml
• Connecting my localhost in 0.0.0.0 IP address 

Do I have to configure and use mongoid.yml as well?

Comment: Did you try the host option, and did you try to exec inside your container and ping your mongodb? If this works it's a mongodb config issue, if it isn't, it's a networkconfig issue

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me: Added self signed ssl certificate, configured mongoid.yml, put all the information in uri, added the uri in mongoid.yml as an ENV var